# Not able to migate data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I was trying to migrate my data to mysql database and this error popped up 
`` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'read' (SQL: alter table `messages` add `read` tinyint(1) not null default 'false' after `to`) ``

Before this I was using sqlite and didn't face any such problem.

**This is the table:-**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddReadToMessages extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('read')->after('to')->default('false');
                    });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('read');
                    });
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me 

*-ThankYou*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'false'` is a string, `false` is a Boolean. Change your migration to

```
$table->boolean('read')->after('to')->default(false);
```